# No service for subscription

Tags: azure, certificate, hpc

I am trying to set up bursting to Azure with a Windows HPC cluster. THe cluster already works fine and I can start jobs on the machines on that are on the local network.

When I try and create a node template for Azure nodes, I enter my subscription ID and select the certificate (which I have uploaded to azure already) and I get the error message **No Service was found under this subscription**

[image: picture of error message]

I've followed all the documentation I can find about setting up certificates on head node, local machine and in azure, but nothing I do seems to remove the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you have to have a cloud service created in Azure first, you can do this by doing the following:

`NEW -> COMPUTE -> CLOUD SERVICE`

[image]